# How can I use an AWS HTTP API (not REST API) with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

Amazon released [HTTP APIs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-http-apis-for-amazon-api-gateway/) for their api gateway product fairly recently, and I'd like to use Terraform to spin some up.  I saw that Terraform has [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/apigatewayv2_api.html) for the `aws_apigatewayv2_api` resource, which will create the gateway itself, but I can't find documentation for routes, stages, or any other types of resources that I'll be needing in my gateway.

Are HTTP APIs just not fully supported by Terraform yet, or am I missing some documentation somewhere?

Comment: Wanted to do the same, seems it is not supported as posted by the user below. We have to use V1 with REST API's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

Per the [closing comment](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11148#issuecomment-675475096) on issue [#11148](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11148), the AWS API Gateway HTTP API resources were first generally supported in terraform-aws-provider starting in [v3.3.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v3.3.0). Later releases have already added new functionality.

**Historical answer:**

Indeed, it looks like the Terraform AWS provider does not yet support all of the resources necessary for an API Gateway HTTP API.

The `aws_apigatewayv2_api` resource was released on March 12, 2020 in terraform-provider-aws [2.53.0](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2530-march-12-2020), but implementations of resources such as `aws_apigatewayv2_route`, `aws_apigatewayv2_stage`,  and `aws_apigatewayv2_integration` have yet to be merged.

terraform-provider-aws issue [#11148](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11148#issuecomment-599137797) has links to pending pull requests for the new resources.

Comment: Everything is now available!  Anyone wanting to use the http v2 resources should see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to use http v2 apis is now available in terraform.  There is a good tutorial on creating them [here](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-the-aws-apigatewayv2-api-to-add-an-http-api-to-a-lambda-function/).

Essentially, for a simple gateway+lambda combo you want something like this:

```
# Lambda function
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
    # ...
}

# HTTP API
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "api" {
    name          = "api-${random_id.id.hex}"
    protocol_type = "HTTP"
    target        = aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn
}

# Permission
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn
    principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

    source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.api.execution_arn}/*/*"
}
```